# Adding QListWidgetItem To QListWidget

Tags: c++, qt, qlistwidget, qt-signals, qlistwidgetitem

So I have a class SnapshotPanel : public QListWidget that I am trying to add a QListWidgetItem to dynamically, however it when ever I try I get a segfault. I have verified that my code to add the item is correct as I can add to the list when I construct my SnapshotPanel. However I cannot add to the panel when the code is called via signals and slot, insight into what I am missing would be apprecited.

Here is the constructor:

```
SnapshotPanel::SnapshotPanel(QWidget *parent):QListWidget(parent)
{

  this->setViewMode(QListWidget::IconMode);
  this->setIconSize(QSize(256,256));
  this->setResizeMode(QListWidget::Adjust);

  QIcon icon("icon.jpeg");
  QListWidgetItem *widget = new QListWidgetItem(icon,"Earth");

  this->addItem(widget);
}
```

So is there any reason I wouldn't be able to use the following code when called via signals and slots:

```
{
  QIcon icon("icon.jpeg");
  QListWidgetItem *widget = new QListWidgetItem(icon,"Earth");
  this->addItem(widget);
}
```

Comment: Are there multiple threads involved? Why are you subclassing from `QListWidget`? Where's the rest of the `SnapshotPanel` code? Is this Qt 4 or Qt 5?

Comment: What signal are you using? And where are you connecting it to the slot?

Comment: When posting a question about a problem with code, please post a complete example that reproduces the problem, or at least post code that has the problem itself. All that you've shown is correct - and you yourself would have known that if you just copy-pasted code from your question into a fresh project and tried it out yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it should just work. ***"Slots are normal C++ functions"*** according [the documentation.](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/signalsandslots.html#slots)

If you are using multiple threads you need to look into the connection mechanism. Perhaps you need to use queued connections. You would change your connect statements from:

```
connect(button, &QPushButton::clicked, this, &MainWidget::on_button_clicked);
```

to

```
connect(button, &QPushButton::clicked, this, &MainWidget::on_button_clicked, Qt::QueuedConnection);
```

But read the [official documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/threads-qobject.html#signals-and-slots-across-threads) here. A SO question (basically pointing you back to the documentation) [is here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14080484/qt-signals-and-slot-thread-safety).

Comment: "If you are using multiple threads you need to look into the connection mechanism. [...] You would change your connect statements" That's false. The default, automatic connection already does the right thing.