# Qt IPC communication and thread errors

Tags: qt, sockets, thread-safety

I am writing a QT application which communicates with other QT application using sockets, I have error handling and capture all errors and warnings produced at run-time.

My handler prefixes and messages with some thing like this:

```
S000000000012E000000032623T15:14:40.587WL00000068F../clsListener.cpp[void clsServer::onErrorOccurred]
```

The above translates to:

```
S000000000012    : Step number which is always incremented when a message is written
E000000032623    : Elapsed time in milliseconds since application start.
T15:14:40.587    : Time in day inc. milliseconds
C or D or F or D : C = Critical Error, D = Debug Message, F = Fatal Error, W = Warning
L00000068        : Line number in source
F(relative path) : Relative path to source file and [function name]
```

At some point in the session I can see the following is logged:

```
S000000000012E000000002491T15:39:20.375W:QObject: Cannot create children for a parent that is in a different thread.
(Parent is QNativeSocketEngine(0x6000000245a0), parent's thread is clsServer(0x600000255520), current thread is clsThread(0x600002c35600)
```

It has taken me quite a while to find what is causing this, however I've traced.  Part of the communications between modules sends a heartbeat message and the receiver sends back an acknowledge, it's the acknowledge that seems to be causing this message.

I'm using Qt signals and slots, the slot the causes this is connected to a signal named **void sendAck(const QJsonObject& crobjJSON, QTcpSocket* psckReceiver);**, the slot connected to this signal **void onSendAck(const QJsonObject& crobjJSON, QTcpSocket* psckReceiver);**

The **onSendAck** slot:

```
void clsModule::onSendAck(const QJsonObject& crobjJSON, QTcpSocket* psckReceiver) {
    QJsonObject::const_iterator citFound(crobjJSON.find(clsJSON::mscszMsgType));
    if ( citFound == crobjJSON.end() ) {
        return;
    }
    QString strAck(clsJSON::mscszAck + citFound.value().toString());
    QJsonObject objAck;
    objAck.insert(clsJSON::mscszAddrTo, cstrGetAlias());
    objAck.insert(clsJSON::mscszMsgType, strAck);
    objAck.insert(clsJSON::mscszSource, clsJSON::mscszXMLMPAM);
    if ( mblnReady != true ) {
        sendLater(cstrGetAlias(), objAck);
    } else if ( psckReceiver != nullptr && psckReceiver->isOpen() == true ) {
        QAbstractSocket::SocketState eState(psckReceiver->state());
        if ( eState == QAbstractSocket::ConnectedState ) {
            QByteArray baMsg(QJsonDocument(objAck).toJson(QJsonDocument::Compact));
            psckReceiver->write(baMsg);
            psckReceiver->flush();
        }
    }
}
```

Its the send part of the **onSendAck** where it calls **write** then **flush** that causes the issue.  Can anyone suggest how I might make this thread safe as from searching online sockets are not deemed as threadsafe.

Should I add the response to a queue and the queue is then managed elsewhere ?

Comment: If you create a singleton object that handles this socket connection, create a slot that handles the messages, and then send signals from any thread to the singleton instance, I believe the Qt runtime should handle the message queueing for you and then the messages will only be sent and processed on the thread that the singletone was instantiated on.  https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/threads-qobject.html https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14080484/qt-signals-and-slot-thread-safety

Comment: @RossRogers, thank you, I will certainly look into this.

Comment: The owner thread of psckReceiver is clsServer, where your socket was created.  You have to call write and flush from this thread (clsServer) to avoid the error message. There are some methods to do this: send back the signal to clsServer, or create the socket directly from the thread handling io/processing data.

Comment: @SPlatten, how'd it go? What path solved your problem?

Comment: @RossRogers, haven't had chance to try it yet, will try today I hope...